# Combining 2 arrays where the resulting sums are as close as possible

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, filter, equality

I am hoping someone can help me out with this problem or point me in the correct direction. What I am trying to do is have all the values from array 1 be as equal to each other as possible when taking only 1 value from array 2 and summing them together. Array 1 is much shorter than Array 2. I will put an example down below with some of the real numbers I am using.

---

**For example:**

`array1 = [458.6,458.5,458.4,457.1,455]` and `array2=[5.6,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.8,5.9,5.9,5.9,5.9,6,6,6.1,6.1,6.2,6.2]`

If I were to add `array1[0]`and `array2[0]` together that would equal 464.2.

If I kept going like that through `array1` and `array2` then the resulting array would be `[464.2,464.1,464.1,462.9,460.9]`

You can see the first 3 numbers in the array are all very close to each other only off by .1, but the last few are off by a lot more.

---

Whereas if it could know to use the numbers at the end of 'array2' then the last two values in the resulting array would be much closer to the first 3.

This is where I am getting stuck and not sure how to proceed. I know this is hard because every time the code is run the values could be different and there isn't a set value to look for. It just kind of starts to appear as a pattern.

Thank you for your time and any help you have to offer is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the values within the two arrays always relatively close to each other, as in your example, or could array2 be, e.g., `[5.2, 132.3, -6, ...]`?

Comment: Since you mention the lack of a target value, have you tried using `mean(array1) + mean(array2)` as target?

Comment: @tobias_k They are that close. Those are actually the real values but shortened for the example. In my real-world problem, I have 12 items in `array1` and 140 items in `array2`. Also, they will also be close like in the example and they will never be negative. The numbers are actually weights in grains of items in the real world.

Comment: This might also work well with some simple stochastic optimization algorithm (ES, GA, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was a greedy algorithm, but this might also work well with some stochastic optimization algorithm, e.g. a genetic algorithm, evolution strategy, or a simple hill-climb. Here's a *very* simple example in Python:

```py
import random

def score(a1, a2):
    # sum of squared error from average
    a3 = [a+b for a, b in zip(a1, a2)]
    s = sum(a3)/len(a3)
    return sum(abs(s - x)**2 for x in a3)

def opt(a1, a2):
    cur = list(a2)
    for i in range(1000):
        new = list(cur)
        # random mutation
        a, b = random.randrange(len(cur)), random.randrange(len(cur))
        new[a], new[b] = new[b], new[a]
        # better than current -> keep
        if score(a1, new) < score(a1, cur):
            cur = new
    return cur[:len(a1)]
```

Here, `cur` is the current solution, which is just a permutation of the elements in `array2` (including those not needed), which are randomly swapped and the result is kept if the "score" is better.

For your sample data, this consistently yields this result, which does not look too good, but actually seems to be about as good as it gets.

```
result: [5.6, 5.6, 5.7, 6.2, 6.2]
sums:   [464.2 464.1, 464.1 463.3, 461.2]
```

If this seems to work, the algorithms can be improved further, e.g. keep more than just one parent, or create more offspring per generation, make sure that at least one element in the swap is actually relevant, cache the currently best score, or allow more than one mutation in a row.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is fantastic. Like you said it could be improved a bit further but this deferentially gets me headed in the right direction and is very close to perfect. So thank you again!